# Does OutputSettings charset also change meta Content-Type?

Tags: jsoup

I have to convert a string from content type text/html into application/xhtml+xml and from windows-1252 to UTF-8

```
charset
public Document.OutputSettings charset​(Charset charset)
Update the document's output charset.
```

The html source contains something like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

The current xml/html output is

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
```

The current instructions are

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
doc.outputSettings(new OutputSettings().syntax(Syntax.xml).escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml));
```

Is OutputSeetings able to create a string like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If so, how? Or is there another approach available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, jsoup will do this if you call the [Document#charset(charset)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html#charset(java.nio.charset.Charset)) method. It will add appropriate HTML or XML to the document to specify the character set, in addition to updating the document output settings.

For example:

```java
String html = "<head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1252\"><body>Hello";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

doc.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml); // specify that we want XML output
doc.charset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // update the charset - also adds the <?xml encoding> instruction
doc.select("meta[content~=charset]").remove(); // Remove the obsolete HTML meta

System.out.println(doc.html());
}
```

Gives us:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  Hello
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see. You remove the meta tag yourself as jsoup does not do that for you.

Comment: In this case we do it manually as we're changing from HTML to XML. If just changing charset, and using the standard meta tag, the value is updated inline automatically by jsoup.